# How to create an interactive report using pl/sql refcursor

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracle-apex, sys-refcursor

I need to create an interactive report but instead of running a sql statement I need to run a pl/sql statement

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
USER_ID        Name                 1 java 2 php 3 pl/sql / sql 4 Oracle apex
-------------- -------------------- ------ ----- -------------- -------------
3              Amy brown            N      N     Y              N           
4              Sarah woods          N      N     Y              Y           
2              Johnny paterson      Y      Y     Y              Y           
1              John brown           Y      N     Y              Y
```

If this is NOT possible to do in apex, Is there any way of saving the results from that pl/sql statement in a csv format when you run the pl/sql?

In the interactive report, users will not be able to add or remove anything. Its is only for viewing.

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought - You could use a TABLE function or PIPELINED function instead of a refcursor.  http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need a plsql statement/ref cursor? Is this data not in "normal" tables?

Comment: First populate a collection with your PL/SQL, then source the report from the collection http://vincentdeelen.blogspot.com.au/2014/02/interactive-report-based-on-dynamic-sql.html

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you're getting at with your question but PL/SQL can write out to a file. Look at the UTL_FILE package. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF

Answer (score 1):

As Scott had stated, one option is to create an APEX collection with the refcursor, then create an interactive grid off of the data using the APEX_COLLECTIONS view.  I have built an example to demonstrate this.

Create a Pre-Rendering Process at the point Before Header. Using this method, you can add additional logic to not re-populate the data if the collection already exists or so the data is not refreshed every time a user refreshes their page.

[Set up of Pre-Rendering Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGYH4.png)

Source code of populating the collection:

```
DECLARE
    l_ref_cur      SYS_REFCURSOR;

    TYPE user_skill_rec IS RECORD
    (
        user_id        NUMBER,
        name           VARCHAR2 (100),
        java           VARCHAR2 (1),
        php            VARCHAR2 (1),
        plsql_sql      VARCHAR2 (1),
        oracle_apex    VARCHAR2 (1)
    );

    l_user_skill   user_skill_rec;

    FUNCTION get_ref_cursor
        RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
    IS
        l_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        OPEN l_cur FOR
            SELECT 3               AS user_id,
                   'Amy brown'     AS name,
                   'N'             AS java,
                   'N'             AS php,
                   'Y'             AS plsql_sql,
                   'N'             AS oracle_apex
              FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 AS user_id, 'Sarah woods', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y' FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 AS user_id, 'Johnny paterson', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 AS user_id, 'John brown', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y' FROM DUAL;

        RETURN l_cur;
    END;
BEGIN
    l_ref_cur := get_ref_cursor;

    apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection ('USER_SKILLS');

    LOOP
        FETCH l_ref_cur INTO l_user_skill;

        EXIT WHEN l_ref_cur%NOTFOUND;
        apex_collection.add_member (p_collection_name   => 'USER_SKILLS',
                                    p_n001              => l_user_skill.user_id,
                                    p_c001              => l_user_skill.name,
                                    p_c002              => l_user_skill.java,
                                    p_c003              => l_user_skill.php,
                                    p_c004              => l_user_skill.plsql_sql,
                                    p_c005              => l_user_skill.oracle_apex);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Then, just create your Interactive Report querying the APEX_COLLECTIONS view with the same collection that had the data populated:

[Setup of Interactive Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR12h.png)

Source Query:

```
select n001, c001, c002, c003, c004, c005
  from apex_collections
 where collection_name = 'USER_SKILLS'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Table Function

https://mfaisal1521.blogspot.com/2019/12/example-of-oracle-pipelined-function.html

also that is possible in Apex to export data. if you are trying to export data you can use utl_File but export data on your database server.